# Tapped push notification does not navigate to the required page in ionic app

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

My app doesn't navigate to the specific page after tapping on the notifications alert on the device tray while app is in background.

```
this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe( data => {
    if (data.wasTapped) {
        // Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
        this.postId = parseInt(data.id);

        this.nav.push(PostDetailsRel1Page, {
            item:  this.postId
        });
    } else {
      // Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I am also facing this problem. Did you solve this? If solve this please share your answer.

Comment: Same issue for me. Also, if once I open the app via the notification I navigate to another page and then use the "back button" I then land into the page I wanted to show with the tap on the notification. The page seems to freezed too. Is this the same for you?